# JS: delete first element from array by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array:

```
arr = [50, 40, 50, 50];
```

I need to delete first element, that equal 50 and dont touch another.
This code return only `[40]`.

```
arr = arr.filter(function(e) {return e !== 50}) // [40]
```

But I need

```
arr = arr.somefunction(function(e) {return e !== 50}) // [40, 50, 50]
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: `arr.splice(0, 1);` It changes the array itself and returns removed element(s) as new array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `findIndex` and `splice()`

```js
let arr = [50, 40, 50, 50];
arr.splice(arr.findIndex(a => a === 50), 1);
console.log(arr)
```

If you need it on the `prototype` of the Array then you can define your custom method.

```js
function removeFirst(cb){
  for(let i = 0;i<this.length;i++){
    if(cb(this[i],i,this)){
      return this.slice(0,i).concat(this.slice(i+1));
    }
  }
  return this;
}

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'removeFirst',{
  value:removeFirst
})

let arr = [50,40,50,50];
let res = arr.removeFirst(x => x === 50);
console.log(res)
```

Comment: @KateGurman Consider accepting the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Attention: if item not exists in array it removes the first item! consider check `findIndex` result to not be -1 and then use `splice`.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a flag and change it of the first value is found.

```js
var array = [40, 40, 50, 40, 50, 40, 50],
    found = false;

array = array.filter(v => found || !(found = v === 50));

console.log(array);
```

With a counter, you could specify the amount of value for filtering out.

```js
var array = [40, 40, 50, 40, 50, 40, 50],
    count = 1;

array = array.filter(v => !count || (count -= v === 50));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

findIndex() returns the index of the first occurrence of the function provided.
After that, you can just delete the element using splice().

```
let arr = [50, 40, 50, 50];
arr.splice(arr.findIndex(function(e) {return e === 50}), 1);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to keep track whether you deleted any value or not

```js
let deleteFirst = (value) => {
  let arr = [50, 40, 50, 50];
  let del = false
  return arr.filter(val=> {
    if(val === value && !del){
      del = true
      return false
    }
    return true
  })
}

console.log(deleteFirst(50))
console.log(deleteFirst(40))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a curried function for that.  It does not modify your original array, returning a new one instead:

```js
const removeFirst = (val) => ( xs = [], idx = xs .indexOf (val) ) => idx > -1
  ? xs .slice (0, idx) .concat ( xs .slice (idx + 1) )
  : xs

console .log (
  removeFirst (50) ([50, 40, 50, 50])
)
```

If you prefer to call it like `remove(50, [50, 40, 50, 50])`, then you can just change the first line:

```js
const removeFirst = (val, xs = [], idx = xs .indexOf (val) ) => idx > -1
  ? xs .slice (0, idx) .concat ( xs .slice (idx + 1) )
  : xs
```